# How to activate content type on specific web?

Tags: 2010, content-type, feature, site-collection, features

I have site collection ex: http://microsoft.com/ and i got few child webs:

http://microsoft.com/news/

http://microsoft.com/somethingelse/

```
   <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ContentType ID="0000"
                Name="News"
               Group="my froup"
               Description="Page layout for intranet news."
               Inherits="TRUE"
               Version="0">    
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{3B5B07A0-68DB-4BF6-AAAE-87B77CE430C6}" Name="LookupToPages" />
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

I added this content type to Web scoped feature.

When i am creating site collection and then child webs i got situation where content type created only on root site.

Web feature is activated on both root and child sites.

[image]

How to force sharepoint to create content type on child web?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only have Content types at Site or List level. So, even if your feature is scoped as web the Content types will be added to the Site level (at root web). From there on, content type will be available, to be added to the lists and document libraries in all webs and so on.

Comment: On each web i want separate lookup field configuration inside my content type.

Comment: create two different content types with separated lookup field configuration, and let each web use different content type

Comment: Falak Mahmood this is not possible. Over 20+ webs.

Comment: Would you please describe a little more context here?

Comment: I got parent site and 20+ child webs. For each web news content type will contains some specific fields that described by customer. Those content types will be generated in code and i want to activate common fields or common web separatelly on each child web.